# My Selenide code is not launching the browser but showing pass test case

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, selenide

```
public class BTest implements WebDriverProvider
{

   @Test
   public void launch()

       {
          System.setProperty("browser", "firefox");
          Configuration.browser=BTest.class.getName();
          Configuration.screenshots = false;
          Configuration.browserSize = "1920x1200";

       }
       @Override
       public WebDriver createDriver(DesiredCapabilities arg0) {
          FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
          return new FirefoxDriver();
       }


    }
```

Comment: No assertions in your test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test you just setting configuration but doesn't do anything to actually start the browser. 
try to open some web page. e.g.:

```
open("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks. Working now.

Comment: But If it will open on open("http://google.com"); then what would be the purpose of this code                                                                   
      @Override
       public WebDriver createDriver(DesiredCapabilities arg0) {
          FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
          return new FirefoxDriver();
       }                                                                                                                               in which we write return new FirefoxDriver();.

Comment: @Amar Nath Yadav you might want to use it to create a driver with certain DesiredCapabilities like javascriptEnabled, handlesAlerts and so on.
In your code method accepts DesiredCapabilities but doesn't do with it. So I don't know )